# How to share ArraList<String> among classes in GUI?

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I am trying to make a GUI that has an ArrayList List and it needs to be shared among classes:

```
public class Selection extends JPanel
{

public static ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();

public Selection()
{

//Adding button for user to click.  If clicked, a line of text will be 
//added into ArrayList<String> List

}}  //End of the Selection Classes
```

This is another classs that I want them to share the same ArrayList

```
public class Total extends JPanel
{

public static ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();

public Total()
{

    //Setting up a button for calculating a sum based on the text 
    //in ArrayList<String> List

 }}  //End of Total Class
```

I try to do the following:

```
public Selection(ArrayList<String> List)
public Total(ArrayList<String>  List)
```

But it gives me error.  What should I do in order to one ArrayList to be shared among two or more classes?

Comment: First of all you should use `List<String>` as signature: this will let you change the implementation later on (when you can, always use the interface as signature, not the implementation)

Comment: Second: use `list` instead of `List` as variable name, which is probably the error source; and give us more details about the error (compile time I presume, but what's the message?)

Comment: Note: more generally, follow java naming conventions for your methods and variable names: they should start by a lower case character

Comment: post the error to question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may want a singleton. You can Google how to implement it. For instance create an Enum Table with only one enum in which you provide a method to access an arraylist.

Once you have done this. You can safely use it in both your classes.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach won't work. Static variables are class variables. So all instances of the Total class will share the same ArrayList, and likewise, all instances of Selection will share the same (reference to) ArrayList, however - instances of Total will refer to a different ArrayList than instances of Selection.

That's a mouthful. But what you need to do is pass the same instance of ArrayList to each class, either through their constructors or through a setter method. Alternately, you could have a static method from a different class which returns the same reference to ArrayList.

The important take-home point is that you misunderstand the meaning of `static`. Also, what you're asking about is **dependency injection**. There have been entire frameworks developed to address this problem, the most popular example in Java being Spring framework. Using a framework would be gross overkill for your requirement, but I just thought I'd let you know.

Comment: okey... I move my ArrayList<String> orderList to the main method.  Then I pass it into the class with: public Total(ArrayList<String>  List).   And in the body of constructor I do this.orderList = orderList;  I still can't get the result.  May I ask what did I do wrong?

Comment: @user2789240 try this.orderList = _(NameOfMainClass)_.orderList;